# Get the request uri outside of a RequestHandler in Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

So, within a webapp.RequestHandler subclass I would use `self.request.uri` to get the request URI. But, I can't access this outside of a RequestHandler and so no go. Any ideas?

I'm running Python and I'm new at it as well as GAE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generally be doing everything within some sort of RequestHandler or the equivalent in your non-WebApp framework.  However, if you really **insist** on being stuck in the early 1990s and writing plain CGI scripts, the environment variables SERVER_NAME and PATH_INFO may be what you want; see a CGI reference for more info.

Comment: Yes, first import os and then look into `os.environ['PATH_INFO']` and `os.environ['QUERY_STRING']`.

Comment: I would disagree that it's just a 90s thing. Different apps have a variety of needs. Once I had to ensure a trailing slash in URLs. Instead of webapp, I just checked `PATH_INFO` and set the `Location` header if it was wrong. Of course in general I agree with Woobie that you need a framework.

Comment: The reason I'm looking to do this is to avoid passing this value through a long string of functions. Maybe I need to rethink how I'm writing this?

Answer (score 0):

Since using request outside code handling it is meaningless I assume you'd like to access it from some method called by handler without passing request to it. Your choices are:

1. Refactor code so that request is passed to it.
2. When the former is not possible use a hack by defining a global [`threading.local()`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.local), storing request somewhere in request handler and access it in your method.

Comment: You don't need threading.local() because App Engine Python is single-threaded.

Comment: Haha, you've got me pegged. Look at my comment on Wooble's answer. I'm thinking I'll need to look at re-factoring my code.