# Where go after user login into Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication

What is the difference between the two lines:

A. loginURL = users.create_login_url(os.environ['PATH_INFO'])

B. loginURL = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)

For my App Engine project I want a user to make customized maps. But if they are not logged in, before they can start a new map project, I want to redirect them to login, and then right after they log in, I would like them to see the "make new project page".

Answer (score 3):

To quote the selected answer to [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593483/get-the-request-uri-outside-of-a-requesthandler-in-google-app-engine-python),

> You should generally be doing
>   everything within some sort of
>   RequestHandler or the equivalent in
>   your non-WebApp framework. However, if
>   you really insist on being stuck in
>   the early 1990s and writing plain CGI
>   scripts, the environment variables
>   `SERVER_NAME` and `PATH_INFO` may be what
>   you want; see a CGI reference for more
>   info.

IOW, live in the 21st century: use `self.request.uri`!-)

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingusers.html

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()

        if user:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
            self.response.out.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())
        else:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
```